# What does "fabric of his existence" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I heard this sentence in movie "The Fisher King"

> See, guy goes to work every day, eight hours a day, seven days a week.
>   Gets his nuts so tight in a vice, he starts questioning the very **fabric
>   of his existence**.

Comment: If you google *fabric of his existence* you will find numerous examples and explanations of the phrase.

Comment: I am getting web pages contains this words, but i want meaning of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrase

> fabric of his existence

has the metaphorical meaning that it is the *basis* or *foundation* of his existence.

A piece of fabric has many interwoven threads and if something is

> part of the fabric

[image]

it means it is an integral part of the *material* or the *whole*.